# Timeline Visualization Not Working In Google Apps Script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-visualization

I'm using Google Apps Script HTMLService:

```
function doGet(request)
{
  var html = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('index').evaluate();
  html.setTitle("CBN Producers' Dashboard");
  html.setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.NATIVE);
  return html;
}
```

When I copy and paste the first example from Google Charts [Timeline Visualisation API](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/timeline) to a normal HTML file and test it, it works perfectly. However, when I do exactly the same with a blank project with Google Apps Script, I get nothing, not even an error. Does Google Apps Script not support Timeline or something or am I doing something wrong?

Thanks in advance, guys!

Regards,
Vishal

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, Google Visualization API is not currently supported in GAS. Non of the APIs that use/extend `google` object are supported (yet) due to sandbox restrictions.

For additional info and possible work-arounds, see [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22330542/can-i-use-google-visualization-api-to-query-a-spreadsheet-in-apps-script).

Comment: 'Uncaught script error: 'The only valid numeric escape in strict mode is '\0'' in source: 'https://www.google.com/uds/?file=visualization&v=1.1&packages=calendar' at line: 1'  
'Uncaught script error: 'undefined is not an object (evaluating 'new google.visualization.DataTable')' in source: 'unknown' at line: 0'

Comment: I get the above two errors when testing the code at Caja Playground. The thing is that other charts seem to be working in HtmlService. I'm currently using Table Charts with no problems whatsoever. I know this is a Caja sanitisation issue but I'm hoping there's some workaround or fix for it.