# Google Sheets API v4: Modifying URL in get request to filter data returned?

Tags: google-sheets-api

Is there a way to get a subset of data using Google Sheets API v4 by modifying the URL https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets/SPREADSHEET_ID/values/Sheet1?key=APIKEY[something added to this URL]?

Specifically, I know that you can restrict the result by setting the range. But is there a way to filter the data in other ways through modifying the URL, say returning all rows containing 'John', or something like that?

This question is about Google Sheets API v4.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 6):

Nope, there is no way to do that.  [According to the documentation](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets.values/get) the only parameters for this endpoint other than spreadsheet ID and range are:

- `majorDimension`
- `valueRenderOption`
- `dateTimeRenderOption`

However, all of these control rendering of the returned data and not filtering of the data.

Comment: I had to elaborate already to fit the minimum word limit. :-)

Comment: ... not really sure what else I could add here.  The question is asking "Is there a way to do <X> via <Y>", and the answer is "No."  There's a lot of ways to achieve the same outcome, e.g request everything and filter it on the client side.  But the question explicitly asked "Can you do it by modifying the URL", and the answer is a pretty simple: No.

Answer (score 0):

It seems this feature is not supported yet. I suggest you specify a range i.e., `A1:K10`, and after procuring all data, perform a search.
You can also check this [SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10807936/how-do-i-search-google-spreadsheets) for additional insight.