# find google spreadsheet by title via api in python

Tags: python, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I would like to retrieve data of spreadsheet by searching for the spreadsheet by name. I wonder how it works?

```
result = service.spreadsheets().values().get(title=spreadsheetTitle, range=rangeName).execute()
```

Answer (score 0):

From this [example](https://github.com/burnash/gspread), you can open a spreadsheet by its title or url.

Example:

```
def open(self, title):
        """Opens a spreadsheet, returning a :class:`~gspread.Spreadsheet` instance.
        :param title: A title of a spreadsheet.
        If there's more than one spreadsheet with same title the first one
        will be opened.
        :raises gspread.SpreadsheetNotFound: if no spreadsheet with
                                             specified `title` is found.
        >>> c = gspread.Client(auth=('user@example.com', 'qwertypassword'))
        >>> c.login()
        >>> c.open('My fancy spreadsheet')
        """
        feed = self.get_spreadsheets_feed()

        for elem in feed.findall(_ns('entry')):
            elem_title = elem.find(_ns('title')).text
            if elem_title.strip() == title:
                return Spreadsheet(self, elem)
        else:
            raise SpreadsheetNotFound
```

You can also check these links:

- [How do I access (read, write) to Google Sheets spreadsheets with Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9690138/reading-writing-to-google-docs-spreadsheets-with-python)
- [How do I search Google Spreadsheets?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10807936/how-do-i-search-google-spreadsheets)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [pygsheets](https://github.com/nithinmurali/pygsheets), a python library for google sheets api v4.

```
import pygsheets

gc = pygsheets.authorize()

# Open spreadsheet by title
sh = gc.open('my new ssheet')
```